# browser auto decode url, is this a standard?

Tags: php, browser

if you use the php function "urlencode" encode a url, and then put the result to a form item's value. the value will be decode by the browser. is this a standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kinda de-facto standard yes. but only in modern browsers.
its done for user convienience, so you can put utf8 charactesr in an url and its still pretty to the human eye.
however please be aware that the text is actually still encoded and will be transmittet/requested encoded, it is only displayed decoded.
internet explorer 6 is to my knowledge the most modern browser that does not support this yet.

Comment: xD Internet Explorer 6?! Modern?

Comment: hey! it supports host headers and stuff! xD

Comment: i've tested IE6, it really decode it. and also submit the decoded value to server.

Comment: you mean if you put in "%C3%B6" it gets transmittet  as "ö"? ... no i cant believe that ;). but if you have a link, containing %C3%B6 it will show up as ö in the browser bar.

Comment: well it depends on the encoding of the page. if you copy that link from the browser where you see an ö, to a text field in an ascii encoded page, you will see %C3%B6 again

Comment: yes,double byte unicode char don't be decoded. but '%3F' will be decode to '?', '%3D' will be decode to '=', so i don't know which will be decode and which will not.

Comment: ? will never ever be transferred decoded because its an url control character (only if its the delimiter of path/filename and query string). it seems like i mis understood your question... cant reproduce what you mean. maby you can put it a bit more clearly so i can answer your question appropriately.

Comment: for example. I encode a url (with query string) and let it be a part of query string of another url: http://url1.php?para=/url2.php?else=.. all browser will decode the para as a decoded url.